# bar_label does not disappear immediately in matplotlib even though "labels" set to None

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart, matplotlib-animation

In the Python code below, I have used the 'FuncAnimation' class to animate a bar chart. I like the labels to appear at a periodic interval and disappear before the next label appear. I have a working code but the labels get stacked up. I want a single label at a time; I mean as and when the next label appears the previous label should disappear. I have also added the faulty output.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import animation

def barlist(n):
return [float(n * k) for k in [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]

fig, axes = plt.subplots()

n = 500  # Number of frames
x = range(1, 6)
barcollection = plt.bar(x, barlist(1))


axes.set_ylim([0, 250])

print(barlist(50))

def animate(i):


y = barlist(i)

for j, b in enumerate(barcollection):
    b.set_height(y[j])

for item in y:
    if item > max(y) / 2:
    x_l = item - max(y) / 2
    x_u = max(y) + n
    axes.set_ylim([x_l, x_u])
    
if i % 20 == 0:  # Add labels every 10 frames
    axes.bar_label(barcollection, padding=10)

# Clear previous labels

print(i)


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, repeat=False, blit=False, frames=n, interval=100)


anim.save(filename='mymovie.gif', writer="imagemagick")



plt.show()
```

[Animated graph](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CmpTx2MDUZA8Tuz3MnoPaYplL1URI_o1/view?usp=sharing)